# ServiceStack Custom CredentialsAuthProvider AJAX Call

Tags: c#, jquery, authentication, servicestack

I'm using a ServiceStack custom CredentialsAuthProvider to authenticate against a custom database and it works great with the C# client. I also need to be able to call some of my services via jQuery (on a different domain with CORS enabled), but I don't know how to pass credentials to the service (which requires authentication using [Authenticate]) from an $ajax or $post. Is it possible? I do see examples of using BasicAuthentication but how would that work with a custom auth provider and my custom database?

**Edit**: I worded this question poorly. I'm already authenticated on the ServiceStack side and I have an ss-id. I'm trying to figure out how to call a service method that requires authentication via jQuery with the ss-id somehow from a different domain.

Comment: I'm looking at this Gist and it looks like this guy is solving a similar problem, but I was hoping for something built into ServiceStack: https://gist.github.com/joeriks/4518393

Answer (score 1):

Bit rough, removed the HTML and form/validation code, but taken from a working app.

Fill in your auth 'dto', adding any extra custom properties you need, and adjust url etc. Once authenticated you can call your secured service.

```
var auth = {
    "userName": null,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "displayName": null,
    "email": null,
    "password": null,
    "autoLogin": false,
    "continue": null
};
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/auth',
    data: auth,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json"
});
request.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //redirect to secure service (assuming SS Razor view, or make other request)
    window.location.href = auth.continue;
});
request.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
    console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    console.log(jqXhr);
});
};
```

Comment: Also look at the source for the SocialBootstrapApi which authenticates via ajax.

Comment: Okay, I worded my question poorly. What I meant is, I'm already authenticated, I just need to call a service that requires authentication with jQuery. I'm guessing that would require passing the ss-id in a cookie somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue, after you've authenticated the response sends back a session cookie, further ajax requests automatically send this cookie, you should not have to manually pass it.

Comment: Sorry, re-read question/update, appears to be a cross domain issue. Would need to understand more about your setup, e.g. completely different domains or subdomains? You can override cookie domain via `SetConfig` in your `AppHost` using the `RestrictAllCookiesToDomain` property, e.g. set it to '.yourdomain.com'

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this lately, but your second comment seems to answer the question. I'll try it out and report back.